# ms project : issue in wbs number reset

Tags: scheduled-tasks, project-management, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I have project schedule as below. I need start wbs from number 1 from kick-off meeting. Till Kick-off, I used customised wbs code, ie M1,M2,M3,M4. it is working. From from kick-off meeting on wards I need to start 1 1.1 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.2 etc

**Existing schedule**

```
WBS  Task name
1 M1: Milestone1
2 M2: Milestone2
3 M3: Milestone3
4 M4: Milestone4
5 Kick-off meeting
6 Requirement
   6.1. Requirement collection
   6.2. Requirement priority
   6.3. Finalise requirements
7 Design
   7.1 High level design
   7.2 Low level design
8 Implementation
   8.1 coding
   8.2 code review
9 Testing
   9.1 Test plan
   9.2 Test case preparation
   9.3 Start Testing
10 Delivery
   10.1 Deliver to customer
   10.2 Release resource
```

I need to change above WBS with wbs code as below.

**Expected schedule**

```
WBS  Task name
M1: Milestone1
M2: Milestone2
M3: Milestone3
M4: Milestone4
1 Kick-off meeting
2 Requirement
   2.1. Requirement collection
   2.2. Requirement priority
   2.3. Finalise requirements
3 Design
   3.1 High level design
   3.2 Low level design
4 Implementation
   4.1 coding
   4.2 code review
5 Testing
   5.1 Test plan
   5.2 Test case preparation
   5.3 Start Testing
6 Delivery
   6.1 Deliver to customer
   6.2 Release resource
```

I tried with Project --> wbS -> Define code and Renumber, but both are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom outline code, not the built-in WBS field. Then you can make it any way you want. Name the custom code CWBS or PWBS or something like that so you can tell them apart.